# Split code into tokens (Lexing) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

I am attempting to tokenize the following code:

```
foo ::= 5
bar ::= 15
foobar ::= 20
```

so the output is:

```
['foo', '::=', '5', '\n', 'bar', '::=', '15', '/n', 'foobar', '::=', '20' ]
```

My current attempt is the following:

```
reTokens = re.compile(r' ')
tokens = reTokens.split(source)
print(tokens)
```

However this prints:

```
['\n', '', '', '', 'foo', '::=', '5\n', '', '', '', 'bar', '::=', '15\n', '', '', '', 'foobar', '::=', '20\n']
```

As you can see there is a lot of issues. A couple major problems is:

1. Spaces are not being removed completely
2. Certain tokens are not being split properly (i.e. "\n". adding \n to the regular expression does not solve the issue either as this removes it from the array completely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
from functools import reduce

lines = source.splitlines()
tokens_list = [line.strip().split() for line in lines]
tokens = reduce(lambda x,y: x + ['\n'] + y, tokens_list)
print(tokens)
```

Which will divide the source to its lines, tokenize each line and then make them a single list with `\n`s in between each line.

Comment: Does "reduce" exist in Python 3

Comment: Oh sorry it is python 3, right :) It is under functools. So you should write `from functools import reduce`

Comment: At the beginning of the code. I edited the code i had written.